# jquery change css click

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a menu which is one made by jquery for dropdown. It works fine. But I wanna rotate fa-bars. I wroten codes. CSS codes doesn't work. What I missed?

```
$(function(){
    var a = 0;
    $('.topnavmenuOpen').click(function(){
        if ( a == 0 ){
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            a++;
        } else {
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            a = 0;
        }
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(500);


    });


$('.topnavmenuOpen').click(function(){
                          $('i .fa').css({
    'transform' : 'rotate(180deg)',
    'transition' : 'width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s'
});
                          });

});
```

Comment: Are you sure about this: `width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s` I have not seen this form...

Comment: Yes, I saw it in w3schools. It works in CSS sources. Also it runs with :active. But in jquery, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this selector: `$('i .fa')` which means "An element with the class `.fa` that's within an `i` element". You want `$('i.fa')` which means "An `i` element with the class `.fa`.

Comment: I should have seen it. I tried `i.fa.fa-bars` and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.topnavmenuOpen').click(function(){
                      $('i .fa').css({
'transform' : 'rotate(180deg)',
'transition' : 'width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s'
});
                          });
```

change

```
$(".topnavmenuOpen").on('click', function(){
    $("i.fa").addClass("rotate");
});
```

and add your css page

```
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: is it more stable instead of my jquery sources?

Comment: absolutely. actually you had better take other click function inside that click function